# Why is my NAN_METHOD not recognized?

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I get the following error when trying to run my Node native extension (it builds without error).  I'd like to know why I'm getting this error, since I'm doing everything correctly as far as I can tell.

```
./NodeTest/nodeTest.js:7
tester.Startup();
       ^

TypeError: tester.Startup is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (./NodeTest/nodeTest.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:383:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:496:3
```

Here is the 'nodeTest.cpp' file:

```
#include <nan.h>

NAN_METHOD(Startup)
{
    auto message = Nan::New("Native Startup() method called.").ToLocalChecked();

    info.GetReturnValue().Set(message);
}

NAN_MODULE_INIT(Initialize)
{
    NAN_EXPORT(target, Startup);
}

NODE_MODULE(nodeTest, Initialize);
```

Here is the 'nodeTest.js' file:

```
var tester = require('./nodeTest');
tester.Startup();
```

Here is the 'package.json' file:

```
{
  "name": "nodeTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "compile": "node-gyp rebuild",
    "test": "node nodeTest.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nan": "^2.8.0"
  },
  "gypfile": true,
  "author": "BT",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "nodeTest.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "description": "NodeTest"
}
```

Here's the 'bindings.gyp' file:

```
{
  'targets': [{
    'target_name': "nodeTest",

    'include_dirs': [
      "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")",
      "./src"
    ],

    'cflags': [
      "-Wall", "-std=c++11", "-fPIC"
    ],

    'sources': [
      "./src/nodeTest.cpp"
    ]
  },  # nodeTest target

  {
      "target_name": "copy_binary",
      "type": "none",
      "dependencies" : [ "nodeTest" ],
      "copies": [{
        'destination': '<(module_root_dir)',
        'files': ['<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/nodeTest.node']
      }]
  }  # copy target

  ] # 'targets'
}
```

Comment: I got it working, can you share your directory structure? Because I believe it's the culprit.

Comment: Which directory structure? There's the root project directory and a 'src' directory containing the .cpp file. Everything else is created by Node/NPM, but it's basically a "build" directory is where everything goes as it's built.  I copy the .node file from the build/Release directory up to the root before running so it's where the .js file requires it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error, check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the naming of your files. The entry point of your program is `nodeTest.js` which contains:

```
var tester = require('./nodeTest');
tester.Startup();
```

Then you have `nodeTest.cpp` which will be compiled into `nodeTest.node`.
But by using `require('./nodeTest')` instead of requiring `nodeTest.node` which is what you were trying to do, you were requiring `nodeTest.js` since `.js` is the default extension [require](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) will try.
If it can’t find a `.js` file, it will try a `.json` file. After that, it will try to find a binary `.node` file.

So `nodeTest.js` was requiring itself. In order to fix your problem, either change `nodeTest.js` to `index.js` or use the correct extension when using `require`.

```
var tester = require('./nodeTest.node');
tester.Startup();
```